# GET API calls to pull PDF in R

Tags: r, api, pdf, httr

This code was working perfectly fine until 2021. After a long time ran this for some other project. The cals are successful with 200 status, but Not sure what is the reason the saved pdf or png file does not open. The error I get when trying to open the pdf file is "Adobe Acrobat could not open 'test.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded)."

```
httr::GET(
 url ="https://public.tableau.com/app/profile/joti.gautam/viz/Book3_16512272064090/Dashboard.pdf",
 httr::write_disk(here::here("test.pdf"),overwrite = T),
  httr::progress()
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a 200 because the request successfully returns html. It doesn't link directly to a pdf. A little snooping in the developer tools reveals the correct url for the actual pdf:

```r
url <- paste0("https://public.tableau.com/views/Book3_16512272064090/",
"Dashboard.pdf?%3Adisplay_static_image=y&%3AbootstrapWhenNotified=",
"true&%3Aembed=true&%3Alanguage=en-US&:embed=y&:showVizHome=n",
"&:apiID=host1#navType=0&navSrc=Parse")

httr::GET(url,
 httr::write_disk(here::here("test.pdf"),overwrite = T),
  httr::progress()
)
```

**test.pdf**

[image]

Comment: can you share how you came to the correct url. wondering if this is a tableau upgrade thing the old url use to provide the pdf

Comment: In your browser, hit F12. This opens the developer tools. Go to the Network tab. Now in your browser's search bar, navigate to the page with the pdf. , and down in your Network tab you will see the files such as css, javascript etc that the page loads. The largest of these is likely to be the pdf, but you should be able to inspect each one to find out which contains the pdf.

Comment: @user5249203 I just don't like any of my code lines going over 80 characters, so if I have a long text string to input in a script I break it into pieces and join it with `paste0` so I can see the whole thing at once. It makes no difference to how the code functions, but it makes it a lot more readable, hence easy to navigate and debug.

Comment: Was reviewing the tableau documentation. Looks like the way I wrote the GET call is not appropriate. https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_ref.htm.  I do not see the pdf as viewed in the public link above,  in my real scenario it is an internal server